# Parse push not received

Tags: parse-platform

I am using parse to send push notification to android device. I have just tested one. My device registered successfully on the server and when I do send the push, it succedd. But nothing appeared on my device. Anyone could help? I've check the code and no problem found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When that happened to me in the past, it's usually because one of 2 things:

1. Parse was not initialized correctly in the `onCreate` method of your `Activity` or `Application`
2. Something crashed in `onPushReceive`. You can try putting a few Log.d in that function and observe the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mobile data instead of Wi-Fi for push and see if that works?
Also put this into your code:

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
```

I couldn't get pushes either without that piece of code.